# Where to find dacquoise in Paris?

Tags: france, food-and-drink, paris, local-cuisine

Where can I eat Dacquoise in Paris?

For those who are food-illiterate, here is the definition of Dacquoise from wikipedia:

> #### [Dacquoise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacquoise)
>
> A dacquoise is a dessert cake made with layers of almond and hazelnut meringue and whipped cream or buttercream.[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacquoise#cite_note-1) It takes its name from the feminine form of the French word dacquois, meaning 'of Dax', a town in southwestern France. It is usually served chilled and accompanied by fruit.

Comment: Never had I heard of this before today. Always learning something new. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the answer from a Parisian is probably 'all over' or 'my local patisserie', for those among us who aren't locals,  [Pierre Hermé](http://www.pierreherme.com/) (72 Rue Bonaparte, 75006 Paris, France) is probably a good place to start.  However, they tend to use it as part of other desserts, like their [Gateau](http://www.pierreherme.com/la-cerise-sur-le-gateau.html):

> **Dacquoise** biscuit with crunchy hazelnuts, hazelnut crisp, thin wafers
>   of milk chocolate, milk chocolate ganache and milk chocolate
>   chantilly.

There's a website, Parispatiserries, which [has a review of the shop and especially the dacquoise](http://www.parispatisseries.com/2010/06/23/pierre-herme-montebello/):

> And that Dacquoise itself was really the highlight for me. Not only
>   was the internal texture of it moist and slightly spongy, but it had a
>   beautiful sweetness and surface texture that Mr. Tongue found
>   thoroughly amusing.

As an alternative, though, if you wish to focus on it just as a dessert, [Le Buisson Ardent](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d719054-Reviews-Le_Buisson_Ardent-Paris_Ile_de_France.html) (25,rue Jussieu, Paris, France (Panthéon)) also serves it.

[Tripadvisor has a photo of their dacquoise](http://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187147-d719054-i43609161-Le_Buisson_Ardent-Paris_Ile_de_France.html) and ranks it #245 of 13,636 Restaurants in Paris.